# Ubuntu SFTP & Chrooting

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, chroot

I've been looking around for a few days now, playing around with configurations and following tutorials on this.

I Have two groups: **dev** and **sftp**.

Users within the **dev** group are also part of the *www-data* and *svn* groups. These users are to be **chrooted** to their home directory. I would like them to have access to /var/www either via a symbolic link, or somehow mounting the directory for them.

Users within the sftp group, **cannot ssh**, but should be allowed to sftp.

**Background**

I attempted to configure the sshd_config to allow sftp group sftp only access, restarted ssh and it dropped. Fortunately when dealing with the sshd_config I prepare a failsafe to revert the config and restart by cron every 10 miniutes in this event. Nevertheless, I couldn't find an alternative or get this method to work.

**Edit !!**

After reviewing the answers below, would an alternative be advised? I run Ubuntu - therefore the root user is locked, and `ssh_config` *rejects* root login. Also sudoers has 2 permitted groups within its config, srv-admin and sudo (sudo cannot kill, reboot, upgrade etc).

The group `dev` is to allow the user access to 2 directories, `/home/<user>` and `/var/www`.
The group `sftp` is ONLY to allow the user SFTP access, nothing more, and NO SSH.

Sounds like I'm misunderstanding the use of chroot in thus scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expose a directory *outside* of a chroot environment via a symbolic link (because the path simply won't be accessible).  You *can* expose the directory via a [bind mount](http://fermilinux.fnal.gov/documentation/tips/mount-bind-chroot).  This lets you mount one part of your filesystem on another part of your filesystem.  For example:

```
mount --bind /var/www /home/someuser/www
```

In general, `chroot` environments are tricky unless you are really limiting the number of tools available.  You will need to provide an appropriate set of binaries *inside* the `chroot` environment, as well as all the necessary shared libraries.  This usually ends up being a losing proposition for an interative environment (such as provided with an `ssh` login) if people expect to be able to work normally.

You should be able to provide `sftp`-only access to the `sftp` group using a `Match` block in your `sshd_config` along with the `ForceCommand` directive.  Something like:

```
Match Group sftp
ForceCommand sftp-internal
```

You can include a `ChrootDirectory` option as part of your `Match` block.  The following would `chroot` people to their own home directory:

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

Note the following from the `sshd_config` man page:

> The ChrootDirectory must contain the necessary files and directories to support the user's session.
>   For an interactive session this requires at least a shell, typically sh(1), and basic /dev nodes such
>   as null(4), zero(4), stdin(4), stdout(4), stderr(4), arandom(4) and tty(4) devices.  For file transfer sessions using “sftp”, no additional configuration of the environment is necessary if the in-process sftp server is used, though sessions which use logging do require /dev/log inside the chroot
>   directory (see sftp-server(8) for details).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did attempt to use the Match block, when restarting the ssh service, it dies (unless i remove the match block).

However, after after reviewing the comment below, is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Then you probably have a syntax error in your `Match` block.  Your syslog will have details; you can also start `sshd` in debugging mode (`/usr/sbin/sshd -d`).  Pierce is correct that there are limits to the use of `chroot` as a security mechanism.  I would strongly suggest looking into Linux containers (http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, chroot is for build environments, it's not a security tool. There are [countless ways](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot) for attackers to break out of chrooted environments.

If you are looking to isolate users from each other, the regular permissions model in Linux should be enough, but you need to lock down the environment itself.  Always assume that an attacker is going to break out of the chroot, and lock down from there.

If you want real isolation, a KVM/Xen style solution is probably what you want, but if you insist on using chroot, then you probably want a grsec patched kernel that has some [basic security protections](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options#Chroot_jail_restrictions) that will prevent the most common chroot breaking techniques.

Comment: After reviewing this notice, I've revised, and updated my initial request. Expressing my ultimate goal, I think chrooting may not be what I need.

Comment: You can use LXC (linux containers), which are much more secure than a traditional jail while not requiring mucking about with kernel patches.  http://lxc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think I will look into the alternative you have both suggested, a little research and so on (: Thanks